# Not all sources available when debugging Node.js app in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, node.js

I'm new to node.js application development and I'm now trying to debug an open source project in Eclipse.

I followed the guide on https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger and got the debugger to run. I can set breakpoints and evaluate expressions.

However, I noticed a lot of source files included in the application directory are not available in the Project folder. Whenever I hit a breakpoint and go up the callstack of that break point, it does give the full path and the concerning line in the JS file. But the source of that file is not loaded.

Anyone knows how I can load those JS file into Eclipse?

Comment: Are those source files by any chance `fs`, `http`, `url`, etc? You should just use `node debug` instead :)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Most of them are included through lines like 'require("lib/router")'. I haven't seen the `node debug` command before, so I'll have a look at that as well.